# Is it mandatory to declare volatile for long type instance constants in multithreaded environments?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I have a multi threaded Java program, where there are few constants of long types which are being read in a function called by multiple threads. These read / assignment operations are outside `synchronized` block and these constants are declared in same class as function being called / `synchronized` block.

Is it advisable to make these long constants `volatile`? Once initialized, these constants are not being changed. I don't see any incorrect program behavior as such but just thought to clarify.

This is pseudo code ,

```
public class ThreadSafeClass {
private long long_val = 100;

public int calculate(){

long local_long=long_val;

synchronized(this){
  //use local_long
}}}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a volatile constant, but there are also no constant variables of long type here. There are integer constants, and non-constant long variables. What you're missing here is `final', which would make the long variables constant and therefore elminate your problem.

Comment: Please define what _you_ mean by "constant" (in the context of you program). How do you _define_ your constants? If it isn't using the `final` keyword, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for responses, I said constant because its not getting changed anywhere else in code, though original developer didn't used `final`. I think, making it `final` would eliminate confusion and `volatile` not be needed ( the way variable is being used )

Comment: That would be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `long` constants are declared as `final` and they are safely published<sup>1</sup>, then they don't need to be declared as `volatile`.  The special properties of `final` fields are specified in JLS [17.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5).

If the `long` constants are not `final`, then you need to do a deeper analysis to determine whether they are really constant, and whether the result of the initialization is going to be visible to all threads.

Declaring the (non-`final`) constants as `volatile` would achieve that, but it is not a good (efficient) way to do it.  A deep analysis (i.e. a careful analysis of the happens-before relationships) could reveal that `volatile` is unnecessary.  For instance, if one thread initialized the constants, and THEN called `start()` on all of the other threads that used them, then (I think) you could get away with no `volatile` and no other synchronization.

But ... declaring the constants as `final` is the more robust approach<sup>2</sup>.

---

Re the pseudo-code in your updated question:

1. The pseudo-code version is incorrect, even assuming it was not changed anywhere else.  The issue is whether all threads are guaranteed to see the *initial* value.  The problem is that the memory model does not require `long_val` to be flushed by the thread that creates the `ThreadSafeClass` instance.  That means that another thread could see the default initial value (zero) when it calls `calculate()`.
2. If `local_long` was initialized *within* the `synchronized` block, the pseudo-code would be correct.
3. If `long_val` was `final` or `volatile, then the`synchronized` block would not be needed (for this purpose at least).  (For different reasons ...)

---

<sup>1 - Basically, you need to ensure that no other thread uses the constant fields before the "final" takes effect.  For a final instance field, that means before the constructor returns.  For a final static field, that means before class initialization completes ... noting of course that a static final field that is a compile-time constant is dealt with differently.</sup>

<sup>2 - I'm excluding the edge case where you use reflection to change a `final` field.  That is evil, and it invalidates all guarantees about visibility.  Just don't do it.</sup>

Comment: Here , a long instance variable, initialized to a fixed value and doesn't get changed anywhere in code ( code is written by somebody else ) , not marked as final is being read in a function local variable and that local variable is being used in a synchronized block within that function. I thought that atomic read problem for longs should not be an issue for this scenario.

Comment: @Sabir_Khan Just to get some background, is the program multi-threaded? If it isn't, you really don't need to worry about synchronization or anything crazy like that.

Comment: I'm not talking about the atomic read problem.  I'm talking about a more general problem of whether the reading thread see the correct initial value or not ... when the initial value was set by another thread.  The same problem arises with all primitive types.

Comment: Thanks for helpful insights, I have added psuedo code to question based on my recall as actual code is on office PC and I currently don't have access to that. Original developer might have some other intentions but I recall not seeing `long_val` being changed anywhere.

Comment: The pseudo-code version is incorrect, but if `local_long` was initialized within the `synchronized` block, it would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

If something is a constant, it's value cannot be changed.

The way I see the `volatile` keyword is basically the caching police. This will make sure that if the value of a variable is changed, then the change is reflected on all threads that access the variable.

But since constants never change, there is never any use for this, since you can't run into hangs or anything due to caching. Since constants are normally marked `final`, this isn't necessary.

Here's an example of a hang I was talking about:

```
static boolean done = false;
public boolean isDone() 
{
    return done;
}
```

On another thread...

```
// do something, wait until this other thing is done...

while (! isDone()) 
{
    // Even if the thing becomes done, this is infinite: the value has been cached.
}

// when something else is done, then do the next thing.
```

---

One extra thing, if the constant is already `final`, then marking it as `volatile` will also get you a compilation error. Cheers :)

Comment: ok, program is written by other developer and I don't see value being changed anywhere so I called it constant but its not marked final. Probably, it should be marked final if that is the way its going to behave.

Comment: @Sabir_Khan Well, if it's not going to be changed, there isn't really much purpose of the volatile keyword. I'll provide a code example of such a hang that I talked about in my answer.